# simple scala question about httpparser

Tags: scala

i'm a scala newbee. i have one question.
in my code ,i try to import httpparse library like this

```
 scalac -classpath /home/kula/code/201005/kookle/lib/htmlparser.jar     crawler.scala
```

and i run this code.

`scala main`

and it tell me that

```
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/htmlparser/Parser
```

at FetchActor$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(crawler.scala:21)
 at FetchActor$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(crawler.scala:13)
 at scala.actors.Reaction.run(Reaction.scala:78)
 at scala.actors.FJTask$Wrap.run(Unknown Source)
 at scala.actors.FJTaskRunner.scanWhileIdling(Unknown Source)
 at scala.actors.FJTaskRunner.run(Unknown Source)

i check the file./home/kula/code/201005/kookle/lib/htmlparser.jar  and it is no problem.anyone can tell me how cause this bug?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
scala -classpath /home/kula/code/201005/kookle/lib/htmlparser.jar crawler.scala
```

i.e. also run it with the required jars on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Arjan's answer should work. However, I would recommend just using sbt and let it figure out all of this stuff for you.